# try tp make rtps server stream over udp webcam video

Tags: udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

spec

> logitech web cam
> gstream-1.0
> ubuntu 22.04

Try to stream

> webcam -> udp stream -> rtsp server -> watch the stream

first try to stream the udp stream from the webcam

> gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 
> videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 
> x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1024 speed-preset=ultrafast 
> rtph264pay ! udpsink host=10.10.10.68 port=8554

and it seemed fine

> x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1024 speed-preset=ultrafast 
> rtph264pay ! udpsink host=10.10.10.68 port=8554
> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
> Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
> Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
> New clock: GstSystemClock
> Redistribute latency...
> Redistribute latency...
> 0:15:15.2 / 99:99:99.

Next try to convert UDP stream to rtsp

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8554 
caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" 
! rtph264depay 
! h264parse 
! avdec_h264 
! videoconvert 
! autovideosink sync=false

But here I got the following errors

> rtspclientsink location=rtsp://10.10.10.68:8554/test
> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
> Progress: (open) Opening Stream
> Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://10.10.10.68:8554/test
> Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
> Prerolled, waiting for progress to finish...
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
> /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Depay:rtph264depay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264
> Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPClientSink:rtspclientsink0: Could not read from resource.
> Additional debug info:
> ../gst/rtsp-sink/gstrtspclientsink.c(2953): gst_rtsp_client_sink_try_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPClientSink:rtspclientsink0:
> Could not receive message. (Timeout while waiting for server response)
> ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
> Setting pipeline to NULL ...
> Freeing pipeline ...